# Couchbase lite on Android not persisting document

Tags: android, persistence, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I'm new to Couchbase lite. On adding a document, I am able to get the document back with the exact data. But on deleting the database, re-creating it, and then creating a new document, I'm still getting the older document.

On debugging, I found that while writing, it does so to the 'store', whereas while reading, it reads it from the 'docCache'.

The steps I followed are:

1) Writing first time:

```
Document doc = database.getDocument(DOC_ID);
doc.putProperties(map);
```

2) Reading first time:

```
Document doc = database.getDocument(DOC_ID);
Map<String, Object> map = doc.getProperties();
```

3) Delete database and re-create it: This is the only way I found to delete all the documents

```
if (database != null) {
    database.delete();
    database = null;
}

DatabaseOptions options = new DatabaseOptions();
options.setCreate(create);
database = manager.openDatabase(dbName, options);
```

4) I follow steps 1 and 2 again.

Now, I get the older document's data, not the new one I added in step 4. I've also tried to get the document after deleting the document, but did not get anything.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: My first thought would be confirm that the database is not null for some reason at the point of 3.  Also as a sanity check, steps 1 and 2 are being added with *different* data each time right?

Comment: @borrrden, yes different data is added each time - actually a list with one element missing. I did not understand your statement about step 3.

Comment: What I meant was is "database.delete()" actually getting called (i.e. not null) and are you working with the same database instance?

Comment: @borrrden, i've made the database 'null' after deleting it. Therefore, it's a new instance being created afterwards. But I did check the database addresses, and it looks like it's being persisted even after being deleted. So thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Do you want to move your comments to an 'answer' so I can mark it right? I'll explain more at the appropriate place.

Comment: I'm not sure which part of that was the answer?  Is it that you have two database handles, and you are deleting one of them and accessing the other?

Comment: @borrrden, i was accessing the database via both a service and the app (both in the same process). I deleted the one in the service, and continued to use the one in the app

Comment: I hope you are using the same manager to mange them otherwise your thread safety is going to be non-existent, but I'll write.  By the way the piece of info about two different handles was a big omission from your original post ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments you mentioned that you are using two database handles.  If you are not using the same `Manager` to get the handles then this is a big problem.  If you are, then both databases should be the same reference and when you delete it there will be an error when you try to access the other one.  If you aren't then you can easily corrupt your data once multiple threads start accessing both of them.

Comment: So, if I'm writing to the database from a service running in a different process, I won't be able to read from the same database in the app's process?

Comment: You will kind of be able to but you will run into caching problems and you won't be able to see what one handle wrote from the other handle because it won't know there is new data.  It is expected that you only use one handle to a given database.  If you are interested in sharing between them you should use replication.

Comment: But with replication, there will be two databases (in sync). Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

> Delete database and re-create it: This is the only way I found to
>   delete all the documents

A way to delete all documents is to create a [View](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/develop/training/build-first-android-app/couchbase-lite-views/index.html) that has all of your documents. Then iterate on the Query results of the View, and on each document you iterate on perform a delete:

```
final View allDocumentsView = couchDatabase.getView("allDocumentsView");
if (allDocumentsView.getMap() == null) {
    allDocumentsView.setMap(
            new Mapper() {
                @Override
                public void map(Map<String, Object> document, Emitter emitter) {
                    if (doc != null) {
                        emitter.emit((String) document.get("_id"), document);
                    }
                }
            }, "1" 
    );
}

final Query allDocumentsQuery = allDocumentsView.createQuery();
try {
    for (Iterator<QueryRow> iterator = allDocumentsQuery.run(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        iterator.next().getDocument().delete();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error", "Error deleting document.", e);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to make any difference. It looks like there is something else going on... maybe the store and cache are not in sync, or some such thing!